# How to move the a bar chart a litle bit up

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning d3.js but I am unable to move the chart a litle bit up to fit it with the x axis. Probably the problem is that I have not to move the chart, I should move the axis but when I try to do it all is a mess. This is what I have.

This is the code:

```
 function createBarChart(allData){
      var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([
                        d3.min(allData, function(d){return d.DATE}),
                        d3.max(allData, function(d){return d.DATE})
                      ])
                      .range([
                        padding+50, w-padding
                      ]);


        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([ 0, d3.max(allData, function(d){ return d.VALUE})])
                      .range([
                        h-padding+3, padding
                      ]);

       var xAxisGen = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom'); 
       var yAxisGen = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left').ticks(10);

       var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({"width": w, "height": h  });

       var yAxis = svg.append("g").call(yAxisGen).attr("class", "axis")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(" + 70 +")");
       var xAxis = svg.append("g").call(xAxisGen).attr("class", "axis")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h-padding) +")");

        svg.selectAll("rect")
          .data(allData)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
        .attr({
          x: (function (d) { return xScale(d.DATE); }),
          y: (function (d) { return yScale(d.VALUE); }),
          width: "8px",
          height: function(d){ return d.VALUE; },
          "fill": "#5CACEE"
        });

      };
```

and here is the project on codepen.
http://codepen.io/DiazPedroAbel/pen/wzovdK?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: height of every rect you're adding should be also a product of `yScale` function subtracted from general height (as far as it's vertical scale).

so instead of this
`height: function(d){ return d.VALUE; }`

use 
`height: function(d){ return h - padding - yScale(d.VALUE); }`

Comment: That completely make the work. That make sense, as long it is scaled you have to scale it but I was trying to change just the parameters.

Another question I have is, my chart seems to have less data than what it is on the original. When I creater the chart all the data was there but once I scale it I had those blank spaces between each bar and apparently less data.

Comment: Well, your chart has all data, but some of its pieces are stacked along - it could be easily noticed over HTML structure inspection. It happens because of incorrect date representation in your data entries - you treat all dates as numbers (as it is defined in your datasource) not as dates. Thus your xScale has domain from 19471001 to 20131001. Difference between entries within one year is too subtle to be noticed. So you definitely should fix your xScale creation method and explicitly cast d.DATE to real date.

Comment: Here is updated code http://codepen.io/stm/pen/bwgorQ?editors=0010 
Notice changes made to xScale (changed type of scale LoC#22; casted date type LoC#25,28) and its usage when generating rects (type casting LoC#57)and removed regex manipulation in LoC#110

Comment: Thanks a lot, that completely worked. Is it posible to make a chart responsive? I tried putting it into a div an controlling from there the sizes in % but the bars do not fit.

Comment: The most simple solution is to make `h` and `w` variables connected with  `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` for example. Of course it will work once - variables values will be assigned at the script execution. 
I believe it would be enough for almost all cases.

If you want complete responsiveness when chart gets re-rendered after each container/window resize - add listener on resize event on window and re-render in callback. But don't forget to throttle callback fn to avoid performance issues.

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/
Here is pretty good article